# Why EF Core keeps adding shadow properties to migration files? Like AgencyId1, AgencyId2 etc

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I try to create a migration EF keeps adding shadow properties like AgencyId, AgencyId1, AgencyId2. I think the issue is in my configs but I've tried several approaches and none of them worked

Generates stuff like that:

```
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Packages",
            columns: table => new
            {​
                AgencyId1 = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                AgencyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            }​,
            constraints: table =>
            {​
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Packages", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Packages_Agencies_AgencyId",
                    column: x => x.AgencyId,
                    principalTable: "Agencies",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Packages_Agencies_AgencyId1",
                    column: x => x.AgencyId1,
                    principalTable: "Agencies",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            }​);
```

Package:

```
  public class Package : PackageModel
{​
    public int AgencyId {​ get; set; }​
    public virtual Agency Agency {​ get; set; }​
    ...
```

(also tried without virtual keyword)

AgencyConfiguration

```
  internal class AgencyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Agency>
{​
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Agency> builder)
    {​
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Packages)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }​
}​
```

PackageConfiguration

```
  internal class PackageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Package>
{​
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Package> builder)
    {​
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Agency)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }​
}​
```

(also tried without that duplicated config on Package side, only on Agency - doesn't work as well)

There are no duplicated columns with the same name, no duplicated config files or anything like that.

Configs are being applied in CoreDbContext:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {​
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AgencyConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PackageConfiguration());
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is there something in PackageModel that is adding another property?

Comment: @Neil No, there's only Name and Description properties

Comment: Is there another table that references this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why EF Core keeps adding shadow properties to migration files? Like AgencyId1, AgencyId2 etc.

The reason is almost always relationship misconfiguration. In your case, here

```
// Agency
builder.HasMany(x => x.Packages)
    .WithOne() // <-- where is navigation property?
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// Package
builder.HasOne(x => x.Agency)
    .WithMany() // <-- where is navigation property?
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

First off, this by idea is one relationship, so should be configured in one place. This is where separate entity configuration class concept doesn't play well, because relationship involves two entities, hence does not logically belong to any of them.

So, at least pick one of them and configure it there, but *never* in two places. Why? Because my omitting navigation property you are actually telling EF Core to create *two* relationships (with navigation property at only one side), hence the additional FKs.

e.g. *either*

```
// Agency
builder.HasMany(x => x.Packages) // collection navigation
    .WithOne(x => a.Agency) // reference navigation
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId) // FK property
    .IsRequired() // not really needed, default for non nullable FKs
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // not really needed, default for required relationships
```

*or*

```
// Package
builder.HasOne(x => x.Agency)
    .WithMany(x => x.Packages)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AgencyId)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

*never* both.

Or even better, since all this is by EF Core conventions, remove the whole relationship configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanations Ivan, it helped! However, if I remove the relationship altogether it tells that `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Users_Organizations_OrganizationId' on table 'Users' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTI
ON or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.` Is the issue in my entities structure themselves then?

Comment: The message refers to different entities/tables, except these are the real entities and not from the sample. The sample should work w/o configuration because the configuration is setting `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` which is already set by convention. The error you are getting is when you really need to turn cascade delete *off* because of multiple cascade paths in the model. So, check the real case, and remember - any navigation property introduces conventional relationship, so carefully pair them and also keep in mind that non nullable FK introduces cascade delete.